# glassfish load balancer configuration

Tags: java, load-balancing, glassfish-3

I am trying to configure clustering in **glassfish 3.1.1** server. I have made clusters but it deploys application on different port number and different ip i want it shold be handled by the load balancer and application should be run on the ip of loadbalancer only that means if a machine is down the loadbalancer redirects that request on another machine configured in loadbalancer.

How to achieve it? does any one have idea about it? or provide link of tutorial and/or blogs for the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://tiainen.sertik.net/2011/03/load-balancing-with-glassfish-31-and.html

To brief up:

Steps to configure a glassfish cluster with a Load Balancer:

1. Create a cluster
2. Create instances for the cluster
3. Start the cluster
4. Deploy the web application
5. Create a network listener to listen the requests coming from the load balancer
6. Install Apache Web Server and get the mod_jk module
7. Edit the httpd.conf file and workers.properties file in the conf directory of apache web server
8. Restart the cluster, glassfish domain and apache daemon

Note: You might need to keep you firewall off if using any Linux OS.